# Drupal API to check a particular user is logged-in, or not

Tags: users

Is there an Drupal API to check whether a user is currently logged in or not, based on the user ID, such as `is_user_login($uid)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no function like `is_user_login($uid)`, but you can see how the core block "Who's online" is created ([source](http://drupalcode.org/project/drupal.git/blob/b47f95d3013619e33cafdf8b769b2b6179a07956:/modules/user/user.module#l1422)).
Drupal has a "sessions" table, where all current sessions are stored.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal doesn't have such function, but you can use code similar to the following one.

```
function mymodule_user_logged_in($uid, $delay = 900) {
  $interval = REQUEST_TIME - $delay;
  return (boolean) db_query("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT s.uid) FROM {sessions} s WHERE s.timestamp >= :timestamp AND s.uid = :uid", array(':timestamp' => $interval, ':uid' => $uid))->fetchField();
}
```