# Check if user is online

Tags: 7

I need to display an image when a user is online. Like the button of skype that it say if the user is online on skype's system.

How can I "check" if a user is online ? Is there a light module or I need to create a new one ? I don't need any type of block o stats about this user, only know if he is online or not.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14421/drupal-api-to-check-a-particular-user-is-login-or-not/14426#14426

Comment: What do you mean by 'online' exactly? If the user is on your site there's a pretty good chance they're online :) Do you mean "Check if user is logged in"?

Comment: I mean that I need to know if user with uid FOO do some  operation in the last temporal window. "Operations" is like view page, update profile, comment a node and so on. I don't need what he is do, only know if he do something (in a temporal window like now() -5 mins). Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

For readability, and simplicity, I like to use the core API:

### Check if current user is authenticated

[user_is_logged_in()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_is_logged_in/7)

i.e:

```
if (user_is_logged_in()) {
  // User is authenticated
  print $content;
}
```

You can also use

```
if (!user_is_logged_in()) {
  // User is anonymous
  print $content;
}
```

though there's even a user_is_anonymous() function

```
if (user_is_anonymous()) {
  // User is anonymous
  print $content;
}
```

### Check if particular user is logged in

If you want to check if a particular user is online

You can use [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules), or [hook_user_login](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_login/7) to respond to login event

```
EXAMPLE_user_login(&$edit, $account){
  /* do stuff */
}
```

or query the session table for that user session uid

```
// Check if user $uid is online in the last 10 minutes
$online = db_query("SELECT uid FROM {sessions} WHERE uid = :uid AND timestamp >= :time", array(':uid' => $uid, ':time' => (REQUEST_TIME - 600)))->fetchField();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show an image for each logged-in user, then you can use code similar to the one used for the block showing the list of currently logged-in users. For Drupal 7, the code would be similar to the following one.

```
function mymodule_logged_in_users($delay = 900, $max_users = 10) {
  $items = array();
  $interval = REQUEST_TIME - $delay;

  // Perform database queries to gather online user lists. We use s.timestamp
  // rather than u.access because it is much faster.
  $authenticated_count = db_query("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT s.uid) FROM {sessions} s WHERE s.timestamp >= :timestamp AND s.uid > 0", array(':timestamp' => $interval))->fetchField();

  if ($authenticated_count) {
    $items = db_query_range('SELECT u.uid, u.name, MAX(s.timestamp) AS max_timestamp FROM {users} u INNER JOIN {sessions} s ON u.uid = s.uid WHERE s.timestamp >= :interval AND s.uid > 0 GROUP BY u.uid, u.name ORDER BY max_timestamp DESC', 0, $max_users, array(':interval' => $interval))->fetchAll();
  }

  return $items;
}
```

`$items` contains the list of users who are logged-in in the specified interval.

Answer (score 1):

This function is based on the code given by kiamlaluno.  I needed a simple way to check if a user is online given the user id.  Below is the code that worked for me.

```
function user_is_online($uid, $delay = 900) {

  $interval = REQUEST_TIME - $delay;
  $ret = db_query('SELECT 
    u.uid,
    MAX(s.timestamp) AS max_timestamp
    FROM {users} u 
    INNER JOIN {sessions} s ON u.uid = s.uid 
    WHERE s.timestamp >= :interval 
    AND u.uid = :uid
    GROUP BY u.uid', array(':interval' => $interval, ':uid' => $uid))->fetchAll();

  if(count($ret)) return TRUE;

  return FALSE;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add to your template file the next check:

```
global $user;
if ($user->uid)
{
    print "User Online";
}
```