# How to check another user is logged in?

Tags: users

There is a lot of questions how to check the current user is logged in, but I need to check another users (by uid for example).
Is there any easy way to do it?

Answer (score 4):

There aren't any functions in Drupal that I am aware of. You'll need to query the database.

```
$time_active = db_query("SELECT timestamp FROM {sessions} WHERE uid = :uid ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1", array(":uid" => $uid))->fetchField();
```

That will fetch the last time that the user was active if they have a current session open.

Comment: A similar method is used by the core block "Who's online" (in http://example.com/modules/user/user.module)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you,

You can use **sessions** table. You can fetch a list of all logged in users by querying the sessions table

```
// Check if user $uid is online in the last 10 minutes
$online = db_query("SELECT uid FROM {sessions} 
          WHERE uid = :uid 
          AND timestamp >= :time", array(':uid' => $uid, ':time' => (REQUEST_TIME - 600))->fetchField();
```

Reference : [Check if user is online](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/55289/check-if-user-is-online)