# Checking if user logged-in by external script, fails

Tags: authentication-authorization, external-scripts

With a script on an external webpage (same domain), I need to detect whether the user that's visiting the page is or not logged in.

[EDIT]
This occurs when the script is into a subfolder.
If it's put into the root folder, it works fine.
[/EDIT]

```
<?php
define('DRUPAL_ROOT',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT.'includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
global $user;

if(user_is_logged_in()){
    echo "logged";
} else {
    echo "not logged";
}
?>
```

despite the fact I'm logged-in, it returns always I'm logged out.
Var_Damping $users, I get this

```
object(stdClass)#17 (4) {
  ["uid"]=>
  int(0)
  ["hostname"]=>
  string(12) "XXX.XXX.XX.X"
  ["roles"]=>
  array(1) {
    [1]=>
    string(14) "anonymous user"
  }
  ["cache"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

where XXX.XXX.XX.X is the IP of the server
and I should be logged in as Administrator (user 1 )

Comment: I guess `$user` never knows which user it's supposed to be and so the session is initiated with just an unauthenticated user. I guess you need to have some endpoint that receives some user identifier (mail, username), load the `$account` from it and check if this user has started a session somehow, then let you return `TRUE` or `FALSE` accordingly, maybe as an uncached JSON response.

Comment: Or you go for some SSO/OAuth solution to have the user logged in externally from where you can programmatically log them in into Drupal.

Comment: @leymannx to load $account should use user_load_by_name($user_name) which needs credentials. The goal is to check if the user is loggedin, avoinding  him to re-enter login and pwd ...

Comment: No, you just need a user ID, or some other unique identifier to get the user ID from. Maybe this one helps: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/56405/15055 and https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_load_by_mail/7.x

Comment: Well, basically the user should login into drupal (via its login page) than should have access to this ""outside"" script. Thus: the should detect whether the user is logged in or not, without giving credentials or else.

Comment: @leymannx I just saw that if the script is put into the root directory of Drupal: it works as it is supposed . But if it is into a subdir: it doesn't work